# Why can't I get the MvcHttpHandler to handle my .mvc requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a project using Asp.Net 3.5 and MVC 1.

Everything runs perfectly on my local IIS, but not after I deployed it to the hosted server.

The web server is IIS7 with integrated pipeline activated (according to the hosting company).

When I go to the root of the web site, www.site.com, the default.aspx makes a redirect to a controller like so:

public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
string originalPath = Request.Path;
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath + "Controller.mvc/Action", false);
IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
}

This works and the correct view is shown. However, when I type the same address in the browser, www.site.com/Controller.mvc/Action I get a 404.0 error. So it seems the MvccHttpHandler is not invoked correctly(?).

The web.config is set up with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true", and a MvcHttpHandler is configured to handle .mvc extensions.

What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out my hosting company did *not* run my application in integrated mode, even though they told me. Solved my problems, but I also got a few helpful tips from Darin.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [good article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETMVC/216_Hosting_and_Deployment_of_an_ASPNET_MVC_Application_in_IIS6_and_IIS7.aspx) which covers different deployment scenarios. There are no particular steps required when deploying to IIS 7 in integrated mode. You don't need a `default.aspx` file and association of `MvcHttpHandler` with the `.mvc` extension in your `web.config`. Here's how your routes might look like if you want to handle both extensionless routes in IIS 7.0 and the `.mvc` extension in IIS 6.0.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

// This is for IIS 6.0
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultWithExtension",
    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// The default extensionless route working with IIS 7.0 and higher
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The `.mvc` extension is needed only for IIS 6.0:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, my problem still persists. Any requests to my controllers gives me a 404.0 error, regardless if I use mvc-extensions or not. The only way I could get it to work was by manually process the request via the default.aspx, which made me believe that the problem was with the MvcHttpHandler.